# Only allow kill-ring-save if there is highlighted text

Tags: copy-paste, mark

I would like to wrap `kill-ring-save` in order to only execute `kill-ring-save` if text has been highlighted - same as in most text editors.

Sometimes I accidentally hit copy instead of paste and then my clipboard is over written, but I have not selected any text for copying. Personally it's a complete workflow killer.

Something like:

```
(defun my-kill-ring-save()
  (interactive)
  (if (TEXT IS HIGHLIGHTED)
    (kill-ring-save)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply want to `(setq mark-even-if-inactive nil)`.

Answer (score 5):

Do not worry about the kill ring ("clipboard") being overwritten: you can recover previous kill ring entries by typing `C-y M-y` (repeat `M-y` as many times as you need).  See Section 12.2.2 of the Emacs manual for more.

If you really want to disable `M-w` when the region is inactive ("not highlighted"), which I do not recommend, you can probably do something like this (untested):

```
(defun my-kill-ring-save (beg end &optional region)
  (interactive (mark) (point) (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg))
  (if (region-active-p)
      (kill-ring-save beg end region)
      (error "Eek!")))
```

Comment: I use `browse-kill-ring` but it's one too many keys and I'd rather just disable.

Comment: This gives me: `Wrong type argument: sequencep, 7269`

Answer (score 3):

As a Mac Os X user, the only regret that I have about emacs is its lack of integration with the rest of the so user-friedly Mac desktop. In particular, I have a mental problem when switching apps, to or from emacs, that is, the change of the copy-and-paste key shortcuts. Even Mac OS X’s Terminal.app understands the `M-c` and `M-v` shortcuts, while in emacs, We’re stuck with those ugly `M-w` and `C-y`.

As I don’t needed it (I have the “prior page” and “next page” keys on my keyboard) , I quickly replaced my `M-v` shortcut by a yank :

```
   (global-set-key (kbd "M-v") 'yank)
```

But I still had the `M-c` problem: I could not just bind `M-c` to kill-ring-save, because I really often use the traditional command bound to `M-c`: capitalize-word. So I wrote this little function in my .emacs, and it really made my life easier :

```
   (defun capitalize-word-or-kill-ring-save ()
      (interactive)
      (if mark-active
          (kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
        (capitalize-word 1)
        )
    )
(global-set-key (kbd "M-c") 'capitalize-word-or-kill-ring-save)
```

I posted this a long time ago on the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-se/CapitalizeWordOrKillRingSave) but an Emacs.SX site is a great home for this trick too !